# Migration changed various unrelated models columns from Integer to Bigint type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I created various migrations to add a boolean column to model `:foo`, backfill it and add a null constraint to it.

I ran the migrations and checked with `git diff` the `schema.rb` file which had obviously changed.

Upon further examination I noticed that various columns all called `cover_file_size` in 5 other models had changed it's type from `integer` to `bigint` when I ran the migrations.

The models are not even related to each other and I cannot think of a reason this happened without my consent.

Is there some kind of default behaviour in Rails that could have originated all these changes? Is there anything wrong with a column of type `integer` becoming `bigint`? So far I haven't experienced any problems running the platform.

Comment: After you run a migration, Rails will dump the current database schema as the schema.rb file, if you had the schema.rb updated by another user and you have a different db setup you may end up with a different schema.rb file with changes unrelated to the actual migration you just ran. I don't worry too much about that, unless you specifically need to use the schema file it should be fine. You could minimize that using the same same database everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with changing columns in a database is downtime. When you deploy and migrate it on production it will lock the entire table while changing this column. If it's a large table it might be noticeable downtime.

Longer explanation:
You didn't specify which SQL (Postgres/MySQL?) you are using. But most of the time changing the type of the column means:

- creating a new column
- copying all the data from the old column
- deleting the old column

To make sure everything is copied correctly the entire table will be locked for this time. Locked means no reading or writing. Hence, the downtime.

As for why this happened, can you provide the Ruby, Rails, and SQL versions? Maybe you updated one of them recently?

Also, are you absolutely sure you had `integer` in your database before the migration? I mean in the database, not in the schema (these are not always the same).

The schema can come from two places:

- It's something that rails generated the last time you run the migration. If since then, you made some changes to your database in some other way it will not be visible in the schema. But the next time you run a migration rails will update the schema to match the current db state.
- It's something you downloaded from git. Maybe another developer has a database that uses `integers`, they run a migration that changed the values to `integer` and pushed it. But your local database uses `bigint`, so now you run the migration it was updated again.

If you are working with other people check the git blame on the schema file to see if these fields were always an `integer`.

Comment: We are using Rails 6.0.3.4 and Postgres. The git blame file shows the changes were introduced by me along with the migration. I absolutely have no idea how the change was introduced or if it has a big impact on the platform itself.

Comment: Just to be sure. When you say "The git blame file shows the changes were introduced by me along with the migration" You mean you introduced the change from `integer` to `bigint` recently, right?

But before that. Was it always `integer` in the schema? Has someone else changed it before you?

Comment: And about the impact on the platform. In general, the `bigint` is better. Simple `integer` is too small and you are at risk of running out of ids if you have a lot of rows in your table. Right now it's recommended to use `bigint`. 
But like I said - it will cause some downtime during the migration.